# Google Play console : where is now located the monthly sales invoice?

Tags: google-play, google-developers-console

Until one or two months ago, the monthly sales invoice edited by Google (corresponding to the money earned with my app and paid by Google to my bank account) was in the Google Checkout. I cannot find it there anymore.

Where can I find it now ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

March 10th, 2017... You can find the monthly invoices in "Settings" => "Payment settings". Use the filter to select only the payments.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 27-Jan-2017** : Play merchants are no longer able to manage their orders through the payments portal. All order management for new and existing orders is now available through the Google Play Store Console

[image]

**Before Jan-2017**

Refer to link https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/answer/7163098?hl=en

1. Click Subscriptions and services
   [image]
2. Under "Merchant services," click Manage. View your earnings and merchant payment threshold, recent transactions, how you get paid, and your profile's settings.
   [image]
3. To see more sales data, click View Transactions

Comment: Do u have any idea how can I perform refund for an individual customer? I can no longer find such option in either Google Play Console or Google Merchant Checkout

Comment: @CheokYanCheng - Click on Order Management screen ( steps mention above ). Then click on any order, it will take you to order details and REFUND button is just below order description